# Middleware for secure API when user registered with socialite

Tags: api, security, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I would like to let my users sign up for my laravelbased application using facebook or similar through socialite.

My users use a mobile app on their smartphones, which accesses the API of my app. Those API-routes are currently secured through the auth.basic middelware

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth.basic'], function()
{
    // ...
});
```

The app interacts with the api restfully through basic protected urls..

```
https://user:pass@myapp.com/api/v1/item/1
```

Now, how can i enable my users to access my protected api-routes, when they have registered through socialite? Is there a Package or a predefined middelware? Also, how would the URLs look like? Is it even possible to allow API calls with both, normally registered users and those being registered through socialite at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 best options in here.

Easiest is to use simple auth middleware in combination of logging in to the API at first before any other API calls

Secondly you can create custom middleware and include a token in your API call that authenticates the user. Example of such call after logging and getting token is below. Middleware gets the url param and checks if this is correct.

```
https://myapp.com/api/v1/item/1?token=123456
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you provice any examles for those options? Especially regarding how the urls/api-calls would look like?